# How to get properties from an object when resolve was returned?

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code in a function:

```
getRecommendedPlan(plan) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       // some code

       let obj = plans.find( x => x.dataDocName === recommendedPlan);
       resolve(obj);
}
```

Ok, now when I return this object, I get the following in my console:

[image]

How can I get the promiseValue?

I already tried the following without any solution:

```
resolve(obj[bonus])
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise and/or https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises or just google. You should start by looking for a very basic learning website, easily findable through Google!

Comment: I'm not clear what exactly you're after. Are you after an explanation of how promises work, or did you not do enough research to know that you should use `.then` to access the results?

Comment: @zzzzBov I used .then and no it returned undefiend

Comment: @Monica, why don't you show what you've *actually* tried then?

Comment: @zzzzBov Ok so the problem was that when I used then, I had to return the promise. I was just calling a function but not returning it. I'll create a version of my code to show here, since it's a company's code, I cannot show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `then` function provided by `promise`

```js
getRecommendedPlan(plan).then(function(resp) {
  console.log(resp); // "Success"
}, function(err) {
  // not called
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Although this was the idea, I had to return the value, like return resp

Answer (score 0):

```
let vplan = obj.then(vplan => vplan);
return vplan;
```